# Can I make modifications to code I typed earlier in the REPL?

Tags: scala

Maybe I'm missing something, but I find experimenting with code in the REPL better excersise for my fingers than for my brain.

Let's say you've defined a simple class (excuse the crappy example):

```
scala> class Farmer(){var name = ""
     | def apply (name: String) = {this. name = name}
     | override def toString():String={name}
     | }
defined class Farmer

scala>
```

Is there a way to get that whole definition and make a change to it, without retyping or 'up-arrowing' line by line. For example, say I just wanted to add one function definition:

```
scala> class Farmer(){var name = ""
     | def apply (name: String) = {this.name = name}
     | override def toString():String={name}
     | def +(surname: String) = {name = name + " " + surname}
     | }
defined class Farmer

scala>
```

In other words, is there a way to tell REPL to replay the full multi-line entry from the previous input (up to a certain line), rather than just one line at a time (as happens when pressing the up arrow)?

In 'Happy land' it would have been nice to do something like, pressing `ALT` and then typing `toString` and then hitting `return`, and then the REPL will retype:

```
scala> class Farmer(){var name = ""
     | def apply (name: String) = {this.name = name}
     | override def toString
```

So basically the REPL retypes your code for you, up to the point you specified.

If anyone have any ideas on how to make using the REPL a bit more efficient than what I'm doing, I'd love to hear from them.

Comment: Keep the code in a text editor, modify it, and paste it back in?

Comment: [ScalaInterpreterPane](https://github.com/Sciss/ScalaInterpreterPane) offers a multi-line editor in a desktop GUI app to call the REPL. You can re-evaluate blocks of code by pressing Shift-Return. I use it precisely because of this feature.

Comment: @0__ I wanted to try that out, but I can't clone the repository on Windows since it has a directory called `aux`, which is reserved. Would it be possible to change this to a different name? http://www.vistax64.com/general-discussion/271873-can-user-create-directory-named-aux.html

Comment: @0__ I'm using ScalaConsole for now, but ScalaInterpreterPane looks great also. Thanks - I'll give it a go a bit later

Comment: `aux` is a reserved directory name in windows?? wow, didn't know that. I have uploaded some binaries now, that should probably work. In any case, I will change that package name in the next version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about copy&paste? Scala will detect that you are pasting from a repl session, and act accordingly (that is, ignore "scala>" and "|"). Though it's more readable if you use :paste mode to do stuff.

Otherwise, you might be happier with another repl. I find that [ScalaConsole](https://bitbucket.org/centaur/scalaconsole/wiki/Home) is pretty good for this kind of stuff.

Comment: I wasn't aware that the REPL ignore "noise" from a REPL session. That's great!